# The 'btn-outline-*' class on bootstrap v4 is not applied

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm coding a simple web app using Angular & Bootstrap v4.3.1.
I'm fond of the "outline buttons" class in Bootstrap v4. But after hours, the class "btn-outline-*" is still ineffective...

I ran *npm install bootstrap@latest* to install bootstrap v4.3.1.
In the **angular.json** file, I inserted in 'architect:build:options:styles :

"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

I tried to install *@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap* but failed to import it in **app-module.ts** : * error: "NgbModule is not an Angular module"*

Actually, nothing works and the result is the same as if the class "btn-outline-*" didn't exist.

HTML

```
<li class="list-group-item" xmlns:disabled="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <h3 class="col-lg-8" style="margin-top: 0; padding-left: 0; vertical-align: center">{{title}}</h3>
      <p class="col-lg-4" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: center">Posté le : {{createdAt | date : 'medium'}}</p>

    <div style="display: inline-block">{{content}}</div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-rating"
              (click)="onLike()">I love it !</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rating"
              (click)="onDislike()">I don't love it !</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

The *btn* class is correctly applied, but the *btn-outline-success* and *btn-outline-danger* are still not working... Do you have an idea to fix it?

Comment: The correct path is `node_modules/[...]`, not `../node_modules/[...]`

Comment: Most likely it is a import issue and consider using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) package.

Comment: @BastienDufour no problem, making an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, your path is wrong. Replace

```
../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
```

With

```
node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
```